# How to reuse a StringTokenizer Object

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I have written some simple code where I am using a `StringTokenizer` to get input data one line at a time and then `parseInt` from it.

```
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(in);

int T = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
int v;
int e;
int testCases;

for(testCases = 1; testCases <= T; testCases++)
{
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(r.readLine());
    v = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    e = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> graph = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(v+1);
}
```

now i want to read the next line using the same object `st` but when i try this

```
 st(r.readLine());
```

it throws an error

> "The method is undefined for main type"

how do I read the next Line. I think i am doing something fundamentally wrong.
or *please suggest some alternative method*.
Here is the input:

```
5   // T
5 6 // v & e
1 2 // error reading this
3 4
5 6
1 4
1 3
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what do you expect `st.()` to do?

Comment: From [the documentation for `StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) _`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code._ The answer to your question is "don't use it in the first place".

Comment: @SJuan76 My mistake. edited it to st(r.readLine());

Comment: @boris How should i do it then?could you suggest some other method

Comment: From the [very same documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), which I take it you haven't even bothered to look at, _it is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead._

Comment: works for me well ...... where is "st(r.readLine());" exactly ? .... "st" isn't a method, is a object

Answer (score -1):

Please use separate method which has your line as argument and returns integer token and get it on your place.

Comment: Do not only provide a URL... quote the important part in your answer, for the content you are referring to can change or even disappear!